# How to send multiple files from android to server node.js programmatically?

Tags: android, node.js, file, upload

I want to send more files from android to node.js server without using file chooser just somes path or files directly.
I try to use this class separately   HttpUpload.java it work as well for me but it do one file for time.

Can helps to modify these code for take this option for upload multiple ?and Thanks

public class HttpUpload extends AsyncTask {

```
private Context context;
private String imgPath;

private HttpClient client;

private ProgressDialog pd;
private long totalSize;

//private static final String url = "http://192.168.1.122:1337/upload";

public HttpUpload(Context context, String imgPath) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.imgPath = imgPath;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    //Set timeout parameters
    int timeout = 10000;
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeout);

    //We'll use the DefaultHttpClient
    client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

   /* pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    pd.setMessage("Uploading Picture...");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();*/
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        File file = new File(imgPath);

        //Create the POST object
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        //Create the multipart entity object and add a progress listener
        //this is a our extended class so we can know the bytes that have been transfered
        MultipartEntity entity = new MyMultipartEntity(new ProgressListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void transferred(long num)
            {
                //Call the onProgressUpdate method with the percent completed
                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                Log.d("DEBUG", num + " - " + totalSize);
            }
        });
        //Add the file to the content's body
       // ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody( file, "image/jpeg" );
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody( file, "" );
        entity.addPart("source", cbFile);

        //After adding everything we get the content's lenght
        totalSize = entity.getContentLength();

        //We add the entity to the post request
        post.setEntity(entity);

        //Execute post request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute( post );
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if(statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            //If everything goes ok, we can get the response
            String fullRes = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d("DEBUG", fullRes);

        } else {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "HTTP Fail, Response Code: " + statusCode);
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Any error related to the Http Protocol (e.g. malformed url)
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Any IO error (e.g. File not found)
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    //Set the pertange done in the progress dialog
   // pd.setProgress((int) (progress[0]));
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    //Dismiss progress dialog
    //pd.dismiss();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your desired imgPaths into an array, then loop over them and execute your `asyncTask`.

Comment: Yes it is an idea ,but I found some alternative solution is calling the class upload  more like this  new HttpUpload(getApplicationContext(), path).execute(); just change the path

Comment: Yes that's the main idea. You call your async class as you mentioned . Happy coding :) .